# Problem with WFS Consuming by using CQL_FILTER

Tags: python, wfs, filter, owslib

for the past couple of days I have been trying to consume a WFS through Python.

I was using owslib but I noticed that the client only uses version 1.0.0 and i tried to apply cql_filters by doing like this

```
from owslib.wfs import WebFeatureService
from osgeo import gdal
import arcpy
from owslib.fes import *
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

filter = PropertyIsLike(propertyname='cql_filter', literal='sorgun', wildCard='*')
filterxml = etree.tostring(filter.toXML()).decode("utf-8")

wfs_link= 'somelink here'

wfs = WebFeatureService(url=wfs_link, version='1.0.0', username = "userX", password = "pw2")

request_data = {"typename":["X:Y"],
                "srsname": "EPSG:4326"}

data = wfs.getfeature(filter= filterxml, **request_data)
```

So I realized that ows only starts to support to filters with the version of '1.1.0', I cannot apply any filters which does not help me. I tried to give it as a request_data parameter but it gives me error.

Is there any other way to do so or any other library that I can use to consume WFS?

Edit1:

So I discarded the first part of the URL, but the request should look something like this:

http://someservice/tkgm.ows/wfs?REQUEST=GetFeature&amp%3BSERVICE=WFS&amp%3BSRSNAME=EPSG%3A4326&amp%3BTYPENAME=TKGM%3Amahalleler&amp%3Bcql_filter=(tapumahallead%20ilike%20%27sorgun%27)

Answer (score 1):

CQL is **not** part of the WFS standard, being rather an enhancement that GeoServer offers so you'll need to use an [XML filter](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/filter_reference.html) (as you seem to be trying to do).

The problem is that you aren't creating a valid filter (try printing out `filterxml` to see what I mean). I'm assuming that you don't actually have an attribute called `cql_filter`. If you want to fetch all records where an attribute (for example called `type`) contains the word `sorgun` you need to do something like:

```
filter = PropertyIsLike(propertyname='type', literal='*sorgun*', wildCard='*')
filterxml = etree.tostring(filter.toXML()).decode("utf-8")
```

which will generate a filter xml:

```
<ogc:PropertyIsLike xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" wildCard="*" singleChar="_" escapeChar="\"><ogc:PropertyName>type</ogc:PropertyName><ogc:Literal>*sorgun*</ogc:Literal></ogc:PropertyIsLike>
```

which is probably going to work.

Comment: It did not work, i got an 500 Server Error: Intenral Server error for url. However if i put propertyname as "cql_filter" it does not return error but and it is the only keyword that does not return error back. In the documentation they said you should use it like this CQL_FILTER (tapumahallead ilike 'sorgun') @ian-turton

Comment: Please edit your question with the request that is being generated

Comment: I added the request url to the question.